# Seaborn heatmap with a custom legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a large dataset which I will simplify for this question. I wish to make a custom legend based on the column value. Let me explain with an example.

```
   df2 = DataFrame(np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 'sensitve'], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 'sensitive'], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 'not sensitive']]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], index = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

I wish to make a heatmap and have a legend on top to see if row is sensitive or not.

First I sorted the values

```
df2 = df2.sort_values('d')
```

and deleted the last column, because it isn't a number and can't be in a heat map.

```
df2 = df2.iloc[:, :-1].astype(float).T
```

After I created a heatmap with sns:

```
sns.heatmap(df2, yticklabels = False)#, cmap="viridis")
```

How do I make a notation up the top of which columns are sensitive or not? Something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could plot a table with those values in a subplot above the heatmap.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 'sensitve'], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 'sensitive'], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 'not sensitive']]),
               columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], index = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = df2.sort_values('d')

d_col = df2['d'].T
df2 = df2.iloc[:, :-1].astype(float).T

# set subplot height ratios to avoid large empty space above the table
fig, (ax_table,ax_heatmap) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize = [8,8], gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[1,9]})
sns.heatmap(df2, linewidth = 1, ax = ax_heatmap)
# only using 2 unique d_col values and setting colWidths to fit your drawing
ax_table.table([d_col.unique()], colWidths = [1/3,2/3], cellLoc = 'center')
ax_table.axis('off')

# setting table size to fit heatmap following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66825885/centering-a-table-with-a-heatmap
bbox_heatmap = ax_heatmap.get_position()
bbox_table = ax_table.get_position()    
left = bbox_heatmap.x0
bottom = bbox_table.y0
width = bbox_heatmap.x0 + (bbox_heatmap.width * 0.8)
height = bbox_table.height * 1.2    
ax_table.set_position([left, bottom, width, height])

plt.show()
```

Which outputs:

[image]

Check out the [table documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html) for further adjustments.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment, it present a great idea.

Comment: 1 more question if you don't mind :) why does my picture has mini subplots everywhere

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by mini subplots?

Comment: I mean if I use a larger set of data, there's nothing there. it works if I slice it to a smaller set, but if I use everything there is not heat map. That's weird. :)

Comment: If you copied my code completely, try removing linewidth from heatmap call. With a relatively small figsize (8 by 8) and linewidth = 1, the cells might be quite small and covered by the lines. Alternatively, if it has the same number of columns but many rows, that could also be covered. Also, make sure heatmap call has ax parameter specified to one of your axes. That being said, it's difficult to know without the specific code and output.